# access Nth node from xpath result set

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlspy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Nth child of a node using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407781/get-nth-child-of-a-node-using-xpath)

How can I access Nth node from the following set.
XPath = /ProcessData/*[starts-with(name(), 'INV')]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below expression will help

```
(/ProcessData/*[starts-with(name(), 'INV')])[5]
```

Here 5 can be replaced with the desired value to get the nth node from the selected(filtered) nodes.