# How to use XPath expression to find element in an array

Tags: xml, xpath

I have few elements of the same type in my xml file and node with number of occurence that I need to use eg

```
<xml>
  <iteration>3</iteration>
  <myElement>123</myElement>
  <myElement>456</myElement> 
  <myElement>789</myElement>
  <myElement>012</myElement>
</xml>
```

Now I need to select 3rd (text of iteration node) myElement node. How to do that using XPath?
I tried

```
(/xml/myElement)[/xml/iteration/text()]
```

but it doens't work. Is it possible?

Of course expected result is 789

Comment: Suggested answer does NOT fit my question. Index of element is dynamic and I needed to convert it to number before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the value of the iteration into a `number` before applying it as an indexer, viz

```
/xml/myElement[number(/xml/iteration/text())]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407781/get-nth-child-of-a-node-using-xpath)

Could you try this one:
`/xml/myElement[position()=/xml/iteration/text()]` ?